# updating boolean attributes in postgresql from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple statement like this:

```
@employee.update_attributes(:subscribed=>false)
```

but this is not updating the `boolean` column field `subscribed`.  It throws a warning saying:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: subscribed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [#update_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001850), not #update_attributes. #update_attribute (singular) accepts two parameters: the attribute name and the value. This is intended for flipping booleans, or updating single values. The semantics of #update_attribute also mean that callbacks won't be fired.

From your code, it's a simple change:

```
@employee.update_attribute(:subscribed, false)
```

Now, for the real reason why your code is failing is because you have someplace where you're using [#attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001796) or #attr_protected in your Employee model. Using #attr_accessible helps prevent injection attacks by only allowing certain fields to be assignable from #attributes= (which is what #update_attributes ultimately calls). The warning originates from #attributes=.

Answer (score 1):

needed `attr_accessible :subscribed` >_<